# HTML: Image not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css

The image displays as a white box with a small image icon in the top left corner.

Html code:

```
<img src="DukeGrafitti_TRANS"/>
```

css code:

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: 215.83px;
    width: 401.83px;
}
```

Comment: issue with image path

Comment: I agree with Pavneet. You don't even have an image extension there, it won't show.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your img src is missing a valid extension, eg: `.jpg` `.gif` `.png`

```
<img src="DukeGrafitti_TRANS.jpg"/>
```

Your code also assumes that the image is in the same directory as the current file you are working on.  So make sure that is the case or provide a full path to the image.

Answer (score 0):

#### I think you need to include the file extension of the image.

Try something like this:

```
<img src="DukeGrafitti_TRANS.gif" alt="DukeGrafitti_TRANS"/>
```

- An absolute URL - points to another web site (like
  src="http://www.example.com/image.gif")
- A relative URL - points to a    file within a web site (like
  src="image.gif")

This answer is referenced from this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp)